# I don't receive answers (dns replies) from dnsmasq

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

The title says it all : I don't receive answers (dns replies) from dnsmasq.

I see Dnsmasq receives queries and treat them (in logs or verbose foreground), but nothing comes back.

For example:

```
stephane@mirror:/home/stephane doas dnsmasq -d -R 
dnsmasq: started, version 2.76 cachesize 150
dnsmasq: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt no-DBus no-i18n no-IDN   DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP no-conntrack ipset auth no-DNSSEC loop-detect  no-inotify
dnsmasq-dhcp: DHCP, IP range 10.0.0.20 -- 10.0.255.250, lease time 12h
dnsmasq-dhcp: DHCPv6 stateless on re2
dnsmasq-dhcp: DHCPv4-derived IPv6 names on re2
dnsmasq-dhcp: router advertisement on re2
dnsmasq-dhcp: DHCPv6 stateless on fd00:2016:22:dec::, constructed for re2
dnsmasq-dhcp: DHCPv4-derived IPv6 names on fd00:2016:22:dec::, constructed for re2
dnsmasq-dhcp: router advertisement on fd00:2016:22:dec::, constructed for re2
dnsmasq-dhcp: DHCPv6 stateless on 2a06:4000:1576::, constructed for re2
dnsmasq-dhcp: DHCPv4-derived IPv6 names on 2a06:4000:1576::, constructed for re2
dnsmasq-dhcp: router advertisement on 2a06:4000:1576::, constructed for re2
dnsmasq-dhcp: RTR-ADVERT(re2) fd00:2016:22:dec::
dnsmasq-dhcp: RTR-ADVERT(re2) 2a06:4000:1576::
dnsmasq-dhcp: IPv6 router advertisement enabled
...
dnsmasq: 1 fd00:2016:22:dec::3/26860 /etc/hosts 2a06:4000:1576:: is mirror.22decembre.eu
dnsmasq: 2 2a06:4000:1576::2/46016 query[AAAA] u38868.mec086b732EDa.sOS.aTLas.RIPE.NEt.22DecEmbre.eU from 2a06:4000:1576::2
dnsmasq: 2 2a06:4000:1576::2/46016 config u38868.mec086b732EDa.sOS.aTLas.RIPE.NEt.22DecEmbre.eU is NXDOMAIN
dnsmasq: 3 2a06:4000:1576::2/60217 query[DNSKEY] 22dEceMbre.EU from 2a06:4000:1576::2
dnsmasq: 3 2a06:4000:1576::2/60217 config 22dEceMbre.EU is NXDOMAIN
dnsmasq: 4 127.0.0.1/32500 query[A] www.facebook.com from 127.0.0.1
dnsmasq: 4 127.0.0.1/32500 forwarded www.facebook.com to fd00:2016:22:dec::3
dnsmasq: 4 127.0.0.1/32500 reply www.facebook.com is <CNAME>
dnsmasq: 4 127.0.0.1/32500 reply star-mini.c10r.facebook.com is 157.240.11.35
```

So here I see well that Dnsmasq resolves FB addresses. Here is the request I made :

```
stephane@mirror:/home/stephane dig @127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com

; <<>> DiG 9.4.2-P2 <<>> @127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options:  printcmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
stephane@mirror:/home/stephane
```

If I start another DNS daemon on the host and make the same query, I get the answer, so it is not firewall related. I get the same result from the local host or remote, ipv4 or ipv6. I don't understand what is the trouble.

Comment: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) Don't edit the word "solved" into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the trouble came because I did not have

```
bind-interfaces
```

in the conf' file. As soon as I activated this option, everything worked great.

Comment: Thanks this saved me as well. dnsmasq stopped responding to queries after a change to the network interfaces and wasn't even logging queries in debug mode, adding this to the config file fixed the problem. Also specifying the same option on the commandline (with -z) resolved it too.

Comment: happened to me on DD-WRT, but only when domain= lines are included in the conf file. this solution worked.